# How did Thanos get the Reality Stone?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

After watching the *Infinity War*, there's one thing I can't get. How did Thanos get the Reality Stone? Gamora kills him when he has two stones, and then he appears with the Reality Stone. I watched this scene 5(!) times, but I can't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Reality is often disappointing. That is, it was. Now, reality can be whatever I want.

This dialogue from Thanos, as he reappears after being killed by Gamora, is enough to understand the scene. He has the Reality stone. So he creates a fake reality for Gamora in which she kill him.

Comment: But when did he get the Stone? And how?

Comment: Before Gamora arrives. It is not shown in the movie how Thanos got the power stone from Xandar & reality stone from Collector. So nobody knows how exactly he got it. But you can imagine the confrontation in both cases based on his & his army's powers. They might show it in 4vengers as a flashback or something. We just have to wait

Comment: Ok, I get it. I thought it was my stupidity :)

Comment: @KharoBangdo You might wanna add that comment into your answer.